# How can I set a default program that isn't in in program files?

Tags: windows-7, file-association

I downloaded a copy of ImageJ off the net.

When I extract the package to `Program Files` the default file association is accepted by Windows.

When I exact the package into my desktop (which solves other programs), I can't set ImageJ as the default viewer for `.tif` files. When I try to open it with the ImageJ exe on my desktop the `Open With` does not display the ImageJ icon despite me navigating to the exe.

Maybe some regediting would help?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting it on the commandline using ftype and assoc. There's a bit more info here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490912.aspx

but essentially, you can use assoc to specify that a given file extension relates to a specific filetype and then ftype to set the command to open it.

Try running "assoc .tif" first to see if there is already a filetype set up and then "ftype thefiletypeyoufound" if there was a filetype.